# How to get simple values from a JSON array

Tags: json, cloud, arrays

The language I am using is java. From my database/cloud-server I am getting a simple JSON array which contains "strings", I want to use these strings and display them to the user. Simple task. However I am totally new to JSON and database so I couldnt accomplish this.
[image]

As you can see in the screenshot, my JSON array is called "object" and it has 3 string values, how do I access them as strings to display to the user?

I tried

```
String a = (String) object.get(0);
```

Also, what if I have array of arrays inside a JSON array? how do I access a particular array inside the JSON array to search for strings inside of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the 2 classes you can use to parse JSON data in Java:

- http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html
- http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html

Values in objects are referenced by the string identifier and you can identify them in the JSON by the use of {} brackets, and arrays are referenced by index and they will be enclosed in [] brackets.  Trying to parse 1 as the other will throw an exception.  You can nest objects in arrays, arrays in objects, or however you'd like.  Once you use get() on an object or array, you can use get() again to get a child object or array.